# Cambiar color a un solo elemento

Tags: javascript, css

Lo que quiero hacer es que, al pasar el ratón por un div entre varios con la misma clase, éste cambie de color y los demás se queden con sus valores iniciales de estilo.

```css
.cunitario{position:relative;float:left;margin:0.5% 1.5%;height:250px; width:250px;border:solid 2px #000;background:rgba(100,100,100,0.9)}
.cunombre{position:relative;margin:85% 0% 0%; height:15%;width:100%;background: #000;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="contenedor">
 
 <div class="cunitario">
  <div class="cunombre"></div> 
 </div>
 <div class="cunitario">
  <div class="cunombre"></div> 
 </div>
 <div class="cunitario">
  <div class="cunombre"></div> 
 </div>
 <div class="cunitario">
  <div class="cunombre"></div> 
 </div>
 <div class="cunitario">
  <div class="cunombre"></div> 
 </div>
 
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Si bien se entiende la pregunta, sería recomendable que aclares sobre qué elementos de qué clase debería ocurrir, y qué estilo debería aplicarse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo fácilmente con CSS. Usando el pseudoestado :hover, que se activa cuando el mouse pasa sobre el elemento.
Cambiar el color de un elemento seria tan facil como declarar en la hoja de estilos algo como:

```
.miclase:hover{
  //Y lo que pongas aqui se ejecutara cuando el mouse pase por encima de ese elemento
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solo debes incluir el el estilo correspondiente dentro de la pseudoclase `:hover`

Ejemplo para que el div se vuelva rojo al pasar el mouse

```
.cunitario:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

Más información en: [:hover - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

Ejemplo completo

```css
.cunitario {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5% 1.5%;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    border: solid 2px #000;
    background: rgba(100,100,100,0.9)
}

.cunitario:hover {
    background: red;
}

.cunombre {
    position:relative;
    margin:85% 0% 0%;
    height:15%;
    width:100%;
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="contenedor">
 
 <div class="cunitario">
  <div class="cunombre"></div> 
 </div>
 <div class="cunitario">
  <div class="cunombre"></div> 
 </div>
 <div class="cunitario">
  <div class="cunombre"></div> 
 </div>
 <div class="cunitario">
  <div class="cunombre"></div> 
 </div>
 <div class="cunitario">
  <div class="cunombre"></div> 
 </div>
 
</div>

</body>

</html>
```